# :active pseudo-class not working on button

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

edit: I have been using Chrome to test. When I opened it in Edge, the :active worked.

So now it appears the issue is with Chrome. I am very new to coding (trying to learn on my own).

Does anyone know why this would be the case?

---

Trying to recreate the google homepage. I am creating the buttons and trying to recreate some of the effects. I am currently stuck on the :active pseudo-class.

I thought I had coded the `:active` to cause a light blue 1px border to replace the gray border of `:hover`. However, instead of that, I get a  black border significantly thicker than 1px.

I tried to include more of the sequence in case it required them all (:link, :visited, :hover, :active), but the problem remains. Any suggestions?

```css
.btn {
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 1px #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.btn:hover {
  border: solid 1px #b3b3b3;
}

.btn:active {
  border: solid 1px #cddbf1;
}

.btn1 {
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.btn2 {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="search-buttons">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn1">Google Search</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn2">I'm Feeling Lucky</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine--I see light blue on click. Can you get this demo to show the problem? Is there any other CSS loading on your page?

Comment: All other CSS works fine. When I click though, I want the border to be only 1px and a light blue color. The current :active selection appears to be black and thicker than 1px. I don't seem able to change the border color on :active.

Comment: [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active) `:active` is toggled when the user presses down the button. You can see that the border color changes while we keep the button pressed. Use `:focus` pseudo-class to get the persistent border on click.

Comment: @isherwood Thank you for your very quick response! After seeing that it worked for you, I tried a different browser... and sure enough! 

It works in Edge but not in Chrome. Any idea why?

Comment: Even in Chrome I do not see the black border you experience; I get the expected light-blue border. Can you check your Chrome settings and see if an accessibility feature is toggled on? When I change "Show a quick highlight on the focused object" to on, then focused elements get a thick border.

Answer (score 2):

You do get the change to active color, but swiftly followed by the change to the hover color so not really noticable.

You may be wanting the focus pseudo class as that remains when the user has clicked even if they move away (until the next click somewhere).

```css
.btn {
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 1px #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.btn:hover {
  border: solid 1px #b3b3b3;
}

.btn:active, .btn:focus {
  border: solid 1px #cddbf1;
}

.btn1 {
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.btn2 {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="search-buttons">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn1">Google Search</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn2">I'm Feeling Lucky</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The issue appears to be with Chrome I have discovered. In Edge, the :active works fine, but with Chrome, it seems to have chosen it's own border property to display?

Comment: It's working fine for me on both Chrome and Edge on Windows 10. (I changed the focus color to something brighter to make sure that it was indeed picking it up during the test). What system are you using?

Comment: Well! I'm utterly lost then! It's Windows 10 on an HP. I guess I'll chalk this one up in "mysteries I do not understand".

Comment: There isn't any subtle setting in your Chrome that can override run time CSS on certain things is there? I don't know of such a setting but I can't think of anything else. Perhaps someone else will see this and try it out so we get a majority decision!